# Using VertexAI (Google Generative AI) in Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am implementing this curl request in golang for connecting to vertexi generative AI models.

I am using the token generated by this command for authentication `gcloud auth print-access-token`.
But the token doesn't last for more than 1 hour.

```
API_ENDPOINT="**-****-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID="******"
MODEL_ID="text-bison@001"

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:predict" -d \
$'{
    "instances": [
        {
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "temperature": 0.2,
        "maxOutputTokens": 256,
        "topP": 0.8,
        "topK": 40
    }
}'
```

Comment: Please check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223871/how-to-get-authorization-token-for-googles-vertex-ai-service